# Can we inherit tags from the project level in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

In Google Cloud, we have a project with a few resources that we build/destroy frequently. After provisioning the resources, we add **network tags** to them. Right now we do this manually but ideally we would like to create **network tags** on our project and have the resources inherit these tags.

I tried this out by adding **network tags** at the project level and then provisioned a few resources in the project. But the **network tags** did not get applied to the newly created resources in the project.

Based on the documentation, inheritance is allow from folder to subfolder but I dont see any mention about project. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-overview#inheritance

Does anyone know if this can be achieved in Google Cloud ?

Comment: Add details on the type of tag.

Comment: Network tags are not inherited. See the answer from Gang Chen below for more details. A network tag is applied to a compute engine network interface. If inheritance was supported that would only apply to child network interfaces and would not affect a parent resource (the compute engine instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you might have confused the `Tags` from `Network Tags`. They are different entities/resources in GCP. Please reference the [Comparison of Tags and network tags](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/tags-firewalls-overview#differences). tl;dr Tags can be used to manage and group GCP resources for purposes such as IAM condition, billing and Firewall policies.

I assume that your interest is in applying firewall policies to group of Compute instances in a project. Under that context, we can refer the tag as `secure tags`. It is sort of an evolution of the `network tags` that allows you to assign logical names to VMs and define your firewall rules in logical groups. Also keep in mind, Secure tag only applies to [Firewall Policies](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewall-policies-overview) which is different from VPC Firewall Rules (a superset).

You can achieve the Tag inheritance for compute resources (see other [Tag supported GCP resources](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-supported-services#supported_service_resources)):

1. Create a Tag at Org/folder/project level (project is lowest)
2. Bind/Assign the Tag and value to a specific folder or project (via console-> Manage resource page or gcloud). Make sure that checkbox **`For use with network firewall`**
3. Create or Update Firewall policies with proper Secure Tag
4. Create VM instances (should inherited the Secure tag assigned to folder or project)